# How to detect an overflow on assembler risc-v?

Tags: assembly, overflow, riscv, integer-overflow, riscv32

I am trying to implement a recursive factorial function in RISC-V assembly language that raises an error if there is an overflow. However, I am struggling to detect it. Is there a solution for this ?

`

Comment: What operation do you want to detect an overflow on?  Addition, multiplication, or something else?

Comment: Also, are you using  `MUL(H)`? What do you consider an overflow? In the simplest case, if you want to stick with 32 bit result, you can use `MULH` and check if the result is non-zero.

Comment: RISC V supports widening multiplication, so you check to upper half to see if it got data;  if so, then the result won't fit in just the lower half.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how GCC implements `__builtin_smul_overflow` or `umul` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)

```
unsigned checked_umul(unsigned a, unsigned b, bool *overflow_happened)
{
    unsigned res;
    bool ovf = __builtin_umul_overflow(a,b, &res);
    if (ovf){
        *overflow_happened = 1;   // set or leave unmodified
                                  // check once at the end.
    }
    return res;
}
```

[clang 16 -O2 for rv32gc on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmGqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFcXLaY9nkMQgRMxAQZPn7ldpgOabX1BAVhkdGx8Qp1DU1ZrSM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzBBADUyAjtANaY6AD6CixetBCbW0ykW9cRdxGonlsAVKgAbtFUtKgA7scEEwEglGEd5iYNABBEwAdisMK2yPugi2xEwChMAGZEdCUVtnq8vlQtjiACJbY7HCJeOiOBinc60Y5fH5/f4QW6PMlmABsGIUkNxUPxKLwpIgJMhCNFBIJH2%2BxF%2BAKBILBIXQZOxlK4OLxBPh5LlKIxBBWDHRmP1oqNtphXgYKWAmp2e2QhxOPguEEdztdty2frwLqOhKeL1o7zZyo5atB4PQkJh8INKODoa1gptSJRRKjJO1lOptPpwWO3pZMZVnO5d3MAsxwrTyIlWylnyoMpb8sV7NVwITropWz1ItzyLtE6t5uIluz49hcONMI4i1onAArLw/BwtKRUJw3NZrFsFMtVphedieKQCJo14t9rE4QA6LibzcATkkX%2BxfMkTdfzMED9E4SReBYCQNA0V8YPghCEPKXd90PDheAUEB4nvPc11IOBYCQNAWASOhonIShiNI%2BgYmIT5sTMABaZADCMLg%2BRg0gsE%2BPA1gANTwTB/gAeQ1ThbxoWgCGiTCIAiB9SAiYJ6gAT3E3glOYYgVOEiJtHaHDb2IthBGEhhaDU3CuMwFhDGAcQrPwDEOm%2BTCrMwVR2i8aT1PIQRKgU2g8AiYhVI8LBfIIYg8Cg7g8N%2BJhgAUAShNExhfP4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQrN0cpWOME9LH0YLMMgRZUASao3MY4SzAwyoDLSFwGHcTxmgkMxSECaYihKCQ4USZJUgEMYWkm3I0l6Ua5iGDqOgELpRj68ZBradaakmJb%2BlKCbhm6Wa9DOhojtmUoNEWc8VjWCR1y3HcFLQrYACUAEkhDcRi%2BPReizGAZAdnK0c%2BTguD21wQgSGvLh5l4HCtHmRY9iYLAYggJ8QGxL9X03LgNDhLg4WxDQzDKOFALAjgINIKDSfiFDeDQjCsLvB9FgIxAUFQEiyLICgICokWUHKqROO43jMBSkSxLivh6Rkyh5KszTVN87XtN0/SHF84zGAIMyLIUrBbKMBz9yczrXIUjyvJ8lXNgCqygpCsKMHWW8opi9TFgSpLFbS3cJNkbLxDyzL5CUNQFN0QbypQSqbC92q8YPRq0ma1r2qqLqIFcC7ymGwpjuyKbqjL%2BbpoYG6xtaNbqk2xptrmva28Okaq4mc7O8u3vK9ul6lie3LXo4bdSHZg9OC2VQAA4%2BUYgCIbs0dJBhjQ4fwIhiCRlGedwjHSGfbFsVfK/b7v%2B%2BGaZ%2BfOdsbm0cfBm2uZ6C2Y%2BzhUd5osJUKRnCSCAA%3D%3D)

```
checked_umul(unsigned int, unsigned int, bool*):
        mulhu   a3, a0, a1            # high half of a * b
        mul     a0, a0, a1            # result = a * b
        beqz    a3, .LBB1_2
        li      a1, 1
        sb      a1, 0(a2)             # just an example of something to branch on
.LBB1_2:
        ret
```

Of course you'd inline this in asm, not actually call a function; making it a function in C is just so we can look at the asm for it on its own, as in [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

You can branch on the high half being non-zero and do whatever you like, or you could `OR` the high halves together across factorial iterations to just check for overflow at the end.

(If you expect callers to often pass inputs that overflow, an early-out on it can save time, and make the worst case performance only about 13 multiplies, as `13!` overflows a 32-bit integer.  vs. a worst-case time of about 2^32-1 iterations with an early out.  But otherwise just an `or` can be cheaper than branching every time.  Of course if you cared about performance, you wouldn't be doing a recursive implementation; that adds a lot of overhead vs. a loop.)

---

As Jester suggested, `mulhu` to get the high half of a full multiply will let you check if the high half is non-zero.  That's the same as checking if the full result fits in the same width as the input operands.

(`mulh` is a signed multiply, so in the general case you'd want to check that it's the sign-extension of the low half, to check for signed overflow if truncating the result to the width of the inputs.  For a factorial with non-negative inputs, you could maybe check it for zero, or better just use unsigned to increase the value-range you can support.)

On a CPU with efficient multipliers, especially one that will fuse `mulhu`/`mul` into a single operation for a widening multiply ALU, the extra `mulhu` is cheaper than anything else you might do, like count leading zeros of the inputs.  Especially without extension-B, since baseline RISC-V left out many instructions that are common in other mainstream ISAs, such as bit-scan.